# Reducing the number of queries kaminari makes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, kaminari

Given the following code:

```
# items_controller
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @files = @item.essences.page(params[:files_page]).per(params[:files_per_page])
  end
end
```

and

```
# items/_essences.html.haml

= paginate @files, :param_name => :files_page

%table.table
  %thead
    %tr
      = sortable :foo
      = sortable :bar
      = sortable :baz
      = sortable :aaa
      %th Blah
  %tbody
    - if @files.empty?
      %tr
        %td no files available
        %td
        %td
        %td
        %td
    - else
      - @files.each do |file|
        %tr
          %td= file.foo
          %td= file.bar
          %td= file.baz
          %td= file.aaa
          %td= Blah
      %tr
        %td
          %b== #{@files.count} files
        %td== --
        %td
          %b= number_to_human_size @files.sum(&:size)
        %td== --
        %td== --

= paginate @files, :param_name => :files_page

%p
  %button.per_page{:data => {:per => 10, :param_name => :files_per_page}} Show 10
  %button.per_page{:data => {:per => 50, :param_name => :files_per_page}} Show 50
  %button.per_page{:data => {:per => @num_files, :param_name => :files_per_page}} Show all
```

I'm looking through rack-mini-profiler and seeing what SQL queries are getting generated

```
Executing action: show
T+2450.2 ms
Reader
1.1 ms
app/controllers/items_controller.rb:72:in `show'
SELECT `essences`.* FROM `essences`  WHERE `essences`.`item_id` = 729
```

and

```
Rendering: items/_essences
T+2991.6 ms
Reader
0.4 ms
app/views/items/_essences.html.haml:2:in `_app_views_items__essences_html_haml__2548715375674979383_70349081205780'
app/views/items/show.html.haml:157:in `_app_views_items_show_html_haml__802676714698420534_70349066386680'
app/controllers/items_controller.rb:81:in `show'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `essences`  WHERE `essences`.`item_id` = 729
```

and

```
Rendering: items/_essences
T+3045.4 ms
Reader
0.6 ms
app/views/items/_essences.html.haml:13:in `_app_views_items__essences_html_haml__2548715375674979383_70349081205780'
app/views/items/show.html.haml:157:in `_app_views_items_show_html_haml__802676714698420534_70349066386680'
app/controllers/items_controller.rb:81:in `show'
SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM `essences`  WHERE `essences`.`item_id` = 729 LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
```

and

```
Rendering: items/_essences
T+3049.4 ms
Reader
1.3 ms
app/views/items/_essences.html.haml:21:in `_app_views_items__essences_html_haml__2548715375674979383_70349081205780'
app/views/items/show.html.haml:157:in `_app_views_items_show_html_haml__802676714698420534_70349066386680'
app/controllers/items_controller.rb:81:in `show'
SELECT  `essences`.* FROM `essences`  WHERE `essences`.`item_id` = 729 LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Looking at the results, there seem to be some redundant SQL calls.

After the `paginate @files, :param_name => :files_page` call is made, shouldn't the number of pages available be calculated, and therefore shouldn't it be known whether or not `@files.empty?` is true or not?

Is the reason that it's not calculated is that the performance gained on avoiding an SQL call for `@files.empty?` is not worthwhile? (I'm new to optimizing Rails applications, so maybe the fact the query only takes 0.6ms means it's not worth worrying about)

I realize that `ItemsController#show` and `@files.each` both select `essences.*`, but that seems to be a mistake on the Rails' application coder's part, not upon Kaminari's part.

I'm using Rails 3.2, and ActiveRecord, and the latest version of Kaminari.

Comment: I think kaminari is optimized considering its generic behavior. I think it try to get latest info from DB and that why it fires repeated query's. suppose you are on first page out of 20 pages (each page showing 50 records) and in some another session someone deleted 100 records and you ask for second page results should be updated (that is 18 pages and relative 51 to 100 records) If you want you can write your own logic send limit and start id in query and handel it at server side.I am not sure kaminari will work on that